# Selector for a range of ids

Tags: css

I need to select all span tag elements within a div with an id `list_{[0-9]}+` having the following form:

```
<div id="list_1234" ...>
    <!-- can be nested multiple levels deep -->
        ...
            <span class="list_span">Hello</span>
</div>
```

How can I do that, e.g. without using jQuery? Is that possible?

Comment: It's possible but it would be *so* much easier using JQuery. Is it an absolute non-option?

Answer (score 6):

If you're happy with css3 selectors you could do something like

`div[id^="list_"]`

But this will also target divs with ids like `list_foo`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with pure CSS pretty easily, just give those divs a class like this:

```
<div id="list_1234" class="container" ...>
```

And CSS like this:

```
.container span { /* styles */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you do'nt use a common class ? You can add many class

```
class="list_1234 mydiv"
```

And your selector :

```
.mydiv span
```

Comment: No reason to put the id as a class. Should be: `<div id="list_1234" class="mydiv">`. Assuming he can change the html.

Comment: why do you think it's an id ?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is:

```
list_1 span, list_2 span, list_3 span... { ... }
```

Is it possible to add a "class" attribute to these divs? That's the proper way to handle multiple elements with ids.